# "Error: Please set the API URL" when buying a Free Membership

Tags: civicontribute

I have a contribution page that has six paid memberships and one free membership.  When the free membership is selected, it kept displaying the error that the Payment Type (Processor)was required.  After I deselected the required field requirement for Payment Processorm, the payment types disappear and they could make it to the "Continue" page, but then CiviCRM shows the "red banner" error page.[image]

Is there a way to allow them to select a payment processor, even though the amount is zero?  Thats what it used to do before version 6.0 (I think).

I am using CiviCRM 4.6.2 on Joomla 3.4.1.  All paid memberships work great.  However when the free membership ($0.00) is selected, the Payment Types - includeds Paypal, Stripe and pay by check, all disappear, but seem to require one be selected before allowing them to sign up for the free membership.

Comment: Can you clarify what version of CiviCRM you are using. Did you mean to say you are using version 4.6.x?

Comment: Can you verify that the Payment Processor you are using for the page is fully set up? This error sometimes happens with PayPal or other processors when the URL to their API endpoint isn't set.

Comment: I thought I responded, sorry.  My payment processors all work fine unless you select the membership for $0.00, then the payment processor selection disappears.  When you go to confirm, it give the error.

Comment: I seem to remember this bug being fixed recently. Can you upgrade to 4.6.3?

Comment: I am using 4.6.3 and I still get the error.   Just checked again to make sure.

Comment: I have updated to 4.6.4, and this problem still occurs.  It appears to be asking for an API URL.  Since it blanks out the Payment processors and the pay by check why is this still happening?  Very frustrating.

Comment: Ok, just for more information, I have to have my free memberships select "pay by check" at the bottom before selecting my  Free Membership.  Is there a way to have the Pay by Check set as the default.  This is a very irritating problem.  It seems that even though the payment processors disappear, it STILL is requiring an API be set.

Comment: I am getting a similar error: "Please set the API URL" when people are selecting a $0 membership. I'm using version 4.6.5.

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE Aug19/2015: The fix is included in 4.6.7**

This bug as reported at https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-14536 seems to be fixed and in QA - if folks can test and report finding that would be great.

The fix is available at: https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/6441

Patch: https://patch-diff.githubusercontent.com/raw/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/6441.patch

[How to do a patch?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/4622/how-do-i-apply-a-patch-supplied-in-the-issue-queue-via-git)