# Payment Processor Error message: 10525: Invalid Data This transaction cannot be processed. The amount to be charged is zero

Tags: civicontribute, civimember, paypal

When using CiviCRM 4.6.4, we notice when adding a $0 (Free) item to a price set, and a user contributes, they are asked to confirm, but then get this error with our Paypal Website Payment Pro processor:

```
Payment Processor Error message: 10525: Invalid Data This transaction cannot be processed. The amount to be charged is zero.
```

When someone chooses a $0 amount, no Paypal payment method is presented on the form, yet it still seems to opt-in to using that processor. We have no other payment processors enabled.

How do we fix?

We also notice that when using CiviDiscount,if we make a 100% off CODE for a membership, it is also rejected by Paypal with the above error.

Comment: Just as a general note - it's worth testing things like this on the latest point version (4.6.5) as this is the sort of thing that is likely to have a fix in a point version. If you still experience it on 4.6.5 then log in JIRA & hopefully we can fix for next week's release

Comment: But beware that 4.6.5 has some significant bugs around search and smart groups, e.g. [Broken smart groups due to CRM-16858](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-16922), [Search for event participants from event page causes error DB Error: syntax error](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-16863) so you might not want to upgrade your production environment until 4.6.6 comes out if these will affect you.

Comment: I am having the identical problem – it emerged on 4.6.3 for us, and is still present having updated to 4.6.6.  We cannot process Free memberships currently, and our community members are putting in $0.01 donations as a workaround.

Comment: After lots of hunting, I found [this stack exchange question](http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/2252/error-please-set-the-api-url-when-buying-a-free-membership) that appears to have the answer to this question.  If I can apply the patch and it works, I'll submit it as an answer here to this question.

Answer (score 2):

**Update your site to CiviCRM 4.6.7**

This was a bug, reported at https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-14536

We had this problem on our site, and it was fixed as of 4.6.7.  Update your site to the latest version, and you should be all set!

Comment: See the links in [this stack exchange question](http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/2252/error-please-set-the-api-url-when-buying-a-free-membership) for a patch, if you would prefer to patch your site instead of updating it.