# CiviEvent registration prevented with “missing fields” error for CiviDiscount free registrations for event

Tags: civievent, registration

We are running CiviCRM 4.6.8 on Drupal 6.37.

We are a theatre company and we use CiviEvent to sell tickets/register attendees for events. We've have set up a membership group for alumni actors and used CiviDiscount to set up the option for alumni actors to register for a pair of comp tickets to any performance:
[image: Screen Shot A]

But, because the registration costs $0, no billing fields appear (nor does the Civi Copy Address"Billing Address same as" checkbox), and the registrant receives an error message and is unable to complete registration:
[image]

Especially since seating is limited, we need to still be able to track attendees, even if they are comped in. This seemed like the best way to allow a particular group of people access a specific discount--non-members wouldn't receive the discount, obviously, and we'd still be able to track who attends which performances and when seats are no longer available.

This also happens if "Pay later" is selected, which I've seen listed as other questions, and appears to be fixed for version 4.6.9, which has not yet been released. Is there a solution in the meantime?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like the same problem as: https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-17082

Looks like you need to apply 2 patches mentioned in the issue.

Comment: Where can I find the patches? I had already viewed that thread but was unable to determine what/where the actual patches were or could be found. I'm a relative beginner, so clear directions to solutions would be helpful and much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Click all on the ticket to read all the comments, it looks like only one patch is needed: https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/6613 - but please read the issue. Instructions on applying patches: http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/4622/how-do-i-apply-a-patch-supplied-in-the-issue-queue-via-git

Comment: I still can't figure out how to apply the patch using SSH terminal access. The command line "cd path/to/civicrm" returns "No such file or directory" I tried installing the new release 4.6.9, but that didn't fix the issue either. If someone can provide me with the coding changes, I know how to access the coding files and have installed patches that way in the past.

Comment: Since the patch is included in 4.6.9, and you are now on that version, applying the patch would have no effect. But if you want to look at code changes: https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/6613/files

Comment: Thank you. Since this doesn't solve the problem in regards to comp registrations for which billing is not necessary, this still unfortunately does not solve my issue. Any other ideas of what to do, or how to address the issue?

Comment: Sounds like you need someone to look at your issue (with having access to your system) See: https://civicrm.org/providers - I work for AGH Strategies who provide the Civi911 service: civi911.com