# After updating civi 4.6.15 to 4.6.16 no access to contacts

Tags: joomla, error, upgrade

After succesfull updating civicrm 4.6.15 to 4.6.16 (files are installed database is updated), I find that access to contactdata in the admin side of my joomla 3.5.1 website has gone. I get a white screen, and after going back to the previous page I get an error notive that says: "Invalid Entity Filter"

I flushed the cache but that does not change anything.
At the frontend of the website I can change my contactdata and save them and get the usual okay message after that. I cannot open the samen contactdata in the backend.
I recreated the site from a backup updated again and got the same results again.

I updated another joomla 3.5.1 site with the same civi version 4.6.15 and that went without any problems.

I set error reporting to maximum in Joomla and do not get any errormessages at all only an empty white screen.

As advised in the comment below I checked the error log inside civicrm.

I got this error-message in a sea of messages:

```
"$Fatal Error Details = array(3) {
  ["message"]=>
  string(21) "Invalid Entity Filter"
  ["code"]=>
  NULL
  ["exception"]=>
  object(CRM_Core_Exception)#448 (10) {
    ["errorData":"CRM_Core_Exception":private]=>
    array(1) {
      ["error_code"]=>
      int(0)
    }
    ["cause":protected]=>
    NULL
    ["_trace":"PEAR_Exception":private]=>
    NULL
    ["message":protected]=>
    string(21) "Invalid Entity Filter"
    ["string":"Exception":private]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["code":protected]=>
    int(0)
    ["file":protected]=>
    string(105) "/home/--deleted--/civi/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/BAO/CustomGroup.php"
    ["line":protected]=>
    int(658)
    ["trace":"Exception":private]=>
    array(14) {
      [0]=>
      array(6) {
        ["file"]=>
        string(105) "/home/--deleted--/civi/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/BAO/CustomGroup.php"
        ["line"]=>
        int(449)
        ["function"]=>
        string(23) "validateSubTypeByEntity"
        ["class"]=>
        string(24) "CRM_Core_BAO_CustomGroup"
        ["type"]=>
        string(2) "::"
        ["args"]=>
        array(2) {
          [0]=>
          string(10) "Individual"
          [1]=>
          string(14) "Verenigingslid"
        }"
```

So: the code trows an exception. However I do not know why. I am logged in in the backend of joomla as superuser, so I should getaccess to all groups in civicrm, with no private execeptions???

Comment: I would start checking error logs in this order, CiviCRM, PHP, Apache/NginX and report back, let me know if you don't know how to access these error logs and I'll give instructions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looks like [CRM-18567](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-18567) and [CRM-18504](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-18504)

Have a look at Chris Burgess [comment](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-18504?focusedCommentId=88586&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-88586), there are couple of commits that seem to fix the issue.

https://github.com/fuzionnz/civicrm-core/commit/a0bcc16171d2f30c4416aeec079bab56c313390a
https://github.com/fuzionnz/civicrm-core/commit/d3e9ab21a0f2256197125854fe6312c3fa0c8c8a

I would recommend to create a backup or replicate your installation in a development environment, apply the commits mentioned and check if it solves the issue.

Comment: Thanks: it is nice to know the problem is probably getting solved already.
I looked at the two github pages with the changed files. What is the best way to copy the changed files, or: is there a way to avoid copy-pasting every change manually?

Comment: Okay: made a local installation, and manually edited customGroup.php using the code found in https://github.com/fuzionnz/civicrm-core/commit/a0bcc16171d2f30c4416aeec079bab56c313390a?diff=unified, and all seems well again!

Comment: If you are familiar with git, here's how you apply a patch via git so you don't have to manually edit the files: http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/4626/872 Also feel free to accept the answer so we keep Stackexchange happy

Comment: Thanks Andrei for leading me to the solution of this issue. I am not at this moment enough of a commandline pro to apply the patch in one go, alas. But I got there in the end: copying and pasting solved the issue for me.

Comment: Civi version 4.6.17 works correct, so the problem got solved.